# Search Gems for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was browsing reddit for the answer to this and came across [this conversation](http://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/1xdrhc/best_search_gem/) which lists out a bunch of search gems for rails, which is cool. But what I wanted was something where I could:

- Enter: *OMG Happy Cats*

  - It searches the whole database looking for anything that has *OMG Happy Cats* and returns me a an array of model objects that contain that value, that I can then use Active model serializer (**Very important to be able to use this**) on to return you a json object of search results so you can display what ever you want to the user.

    So that json object, if this was a blog, would have a post object, maybe a category object and even a comment object.

Everything I have seen is very specific to one controller, one model. Which is nice an all but I am more of a "search for what you want, we will return you what you want, maybe grow smarter like [this gem, searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) which also has the ability to offer spelling suggestion.

I am building this with an API, so it would be limited to everything that belongs to a blog object (as to make it not so huge of a search), so it would search things like posts, tags, categories, comments and pages looking for your term, return a json object (as described) and boom done.

Any ideas?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be best considering the underlying technology for this

--

**Third Party**

As far as I know (I'm not super experienced in this area), the best way to search an *entire* Rails database is to use a third party system to "index" the various elements of data you require, allowing you to search them as required.

Some examples of this include:

- [Sunspot / Solr](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot)
- [ElasticSearch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch)

Essentially, having one of these "third party" search systems gives you the ability to `index` the various records you want in a separate database, which you can then search with your application.

--

**Notes**

There are several advantages to handling "search" with a third party stack.

Firstly, it takes the load off your main web server - which means it'll be more reliable & able to handle more traffic.

Secondly, it will ensure you're able to search *all* the data of your application, instead of tying into a particular model / data set

Thirdly, because many of these third party solutions `index` the content you're looking for, it will free up your database connectivity for your actual application, making it more efficient & scaleable

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL you should be able to use [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search).
I've never used it myself but going by the documentation on GitHub, it should allow you to do:

```
documents = PgSearch.multisearch('OMG Happy Cats').to_a
objects = documents.map(&:searchable)
groups = objects.group_by{|o| o.class.name.pluralize.downcase}
json = Hash[groups.map{|k,v| [k,ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(v).as_json]}].as_json
puts json.to_json
```

Comment: I did see this for sure and might try an implementation of it.